# is it possible to make view controller dim(like alert view controller) except one view of that view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I just wanted to create a view and when it shown then the whole background will be dimmed like an alert view controller. If it is possible then please guide me and if possible then provide me code.

Thank you

Comment: The key is setting the view background colour with some alpha value like 0.7. You can achieve this with a normal view or with view controllers. What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: programatically add A UIView with lower Alpha and BG as Black and Add The view to be Highlighted as Subview in that Created View

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way for doing that is to add a semi-transparent background (e.g. black with alpha less than 1.0) view, which contains the *alert view*. The background view should cover all other views in the view controller.

You can also use a modal view controller which has such a background view as its view, and presenting this controller with presentation style *Over Full Screen*.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Here is the wrapper code  i use in most of my project now a days
protocol TransparentBackgroundProtocol {

  associatedtype ContainedView
  var containedNib: ContainedView? { get set }

}

extension TransparentBackgroundProtocol  where ContainedView: UIView {

  func dismiss() {
    containedNib?.superview?.removeFromSuperview()
    containedNib?.removeFromSuperview()
  }

  mutating func add(withFrame frame: CGRect, toView view: UIView, backGroundViewAlpha: CGFloat) {
    containedNib?.frame = frame
    let backgroundView = configureABlackBackGroundView(alpha: backGroundViewAlpha)
    view.addSubview(backgroundView)

    guard let containedNib = containedNib else {
      print("No ContainedNib")
      return
    }
    backgroundView.addSubview(containedNib)
  }

  private func configureABlackBackGroundView(alpha: CGFloat) -> UIView {
    let blackBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height))
    blackBackgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(alpha)
    return blackBackgroundView
  }
}

// Sample View shown like alertView

class LogoutPopUpView: UIView, TransparentBackgroundProtocol {

    // MARK: Variables
    weak var containedNib: LogoutPopUpView?
    typealias ContainedView = LogoutPopUpView

    // MARK: Outlets


    // MARK: Functions
    class func initiate() -> LogoutPopUpView {
        guard let nibView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LogoutPopUpView", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as? LogoutPopUpView else {
            fatalError("Cann't able to load nib file.")
        }
         return nibView
    }

}


// where  u want to show pop Up
        logOutPopup = LogoutPopUpView.instanciateFromNib()
       let view = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view {
            logOutPopup?.add(withFrame: CGRect(x: 30, y:(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height-340)/2, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 60, height: 300), toView: view, backGroundViewAlpha: 0.8)            
        }
 // for dismiss
self.logOutPopup?.dismiss()
```